# reproduce same oval in different locations android

Tags: java, android

I want to create an oval in the location the user touches, but when the user touches a different location, I want the old oval to stay and a new oval to appear. The old oval just switches to the new location, the old oval is not in the old location. How do you display both of them?

The only way I can think of is to make an arraylist to store the ovals and to make a loop to draw each different oval in the arraylist:

```
Arraylist<RectF> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(new RectF(x, y, x+rad, y+rad));
for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
    canvas.drawOval(al.get(i), paint);
}
```

This method seems inefficient though. Is there a better way to do this?
I tested it and it worked. It was just a bit slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a bitmap first. Then each time a new oval is created, just draw that oval on the bitmap. In such way you don't have to redraw old ovals.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);// reuse the bitmap each time a new oval is created.
canvas.drawOval(al.get('index of the new oval'), paint);
```